# Flutter on iOS 'FirebaseCore/FIRLogger.h' file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have designed and publish the Android version of my Flutter project made in Win10, now I'm trying to publish the iOS version but I get this error when I try my first  `flutter run` on ios:

```
ios/Pods/FirebaseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations/Source/Library/FIRInstallationsLogger.h:19:9: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/FIRLogger.h' file not found
    #import <FirebaseCore/FIRLogger.h>
```

Already I try `flutter clean`  but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

More detail.

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.1+1
  firebase_performance: ^0.4.0+2
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  firebase_analytics: ^6.0.2
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.4.0+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+2
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.2.0+1
  firebase_dynamic_links:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/mrmilu/flutterfire
      path: packages/firebase_dynamic_links
      ref: firebase_dynamic_links
  random_string: ^2.0.0

  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  provider: ^4.0.1
  country_code_picker: ^1.4.0
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.9
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^1.1.0
  slimy_card: ^1.0.4
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0


  esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.2
  rxdart: ^0.23.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
  package_info: ^0.4.0+13

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^3.2.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.9

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/AppIcon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FFDF00"

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/SplashScreen.png
  color: "#FFDF00"



flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```